# No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-3.2, jsr223

I have a Sample JSON response as below:

```
{
"id": 37,
"merchant_id": "39",
"title": "Parker Pens",
"subtitle": null,
"price": 1000,
"description": null,
"images": [],
"image_thumbs": [],
"options": [{
    "code": "color",
    "label": "Color",
    "extra_info": "",
    "values": [{
        "label": "Red",
        "value": "8"
    }, {
        "label": "Yellow",
        "value": "9"
    }, {
        "label": "Pink",
        "value": "10"
    }]
  }, {
    "code": "size",
    "label": "Size",
    "extra_info": "",
    "values": [{
        "label": "Small",
        "value": "4"
    }, {
        "label": "Medium",
        "value": "5"
    }, {
        "label": "Large",
        "value": "6"
    }]
}],
"options_available": [{
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Red"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Small"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Red"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Medium"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Red"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Large"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Yellow"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Small"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Yellow"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Medium"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Yellow"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Large"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Pink"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Small"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Pink"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Medium"
    }]
}, {
    "combination": [{
        "code": "color",
        "value": "Pink"
    }, {
        "code": "size",
        "value": "Large"
    }]
}],
"custom_options": []
}
```

and i have my Sampler as

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

String response= prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("options");
Integer count= jsonArray.length();
vars.put('counts', count);
```

But while running the script I'm getting an error:
`No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)`

In addition to values also (Counts=2). My intention is to get the count of array in "Options" Key ( See response above)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vars.put` doesn't support different value than regular `String` and you are trying to put `Integer` value.

Easy way out by simple convert:

```
vars.put("counts", Integer.toString(count));
```

Another option is save object as is using [vars.putObject](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

```
vars.putObject("counts", count);
```

Also move to JSR223 Sampler, per JMeter [best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting):

> Since JMeter 3.1, we advise switching from BeanShell to JSR223 Test Elements

Answer (score 1):

Go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language as:

1. [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
2. [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
3. [Groovy provides a lot of enhancements on top of Java SDK](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)

Groovy equivalent of your 7 lines of Beanshell code would be:

```
vars.put('counts',new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).options.size() as String)
```